# How to convert to uppercase in c language

Tags: c

I'm writing a code in c language, the function should send the output to main(). Every time I enter string and try to convert it uppercase the message appear "Segmentation fault
"

here is my code:

```
 char uppercase(char inputt[]);
```

inside the main():

```
case 'C': case 'c':
{
printf ("The string: %s \n", uppercase(inputt));

}
break;
```

my function:

```
char uppercase(char inputt[]) {
    int i=0, len[100];
    for(i = 0; inputt[i]; i++) {
        len[i] = toupper(inputt[i]);
    }
    return len[i];
}
```

Thank you

Comment: toupper is in the <ctype.h> library. Is that included in your program?

Comment: @Mic1780, OP said he has a runtime error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting undefined behavior in this line:

```
printf ("The string: %s \n", uppercase(inputt));
```

The format specifier, `%s`, expects a null terminated C string. You are passing it the return value of `uppercase`, which is a `char`.

One potential fix:

Change `uppercase` to have two arguments -- one for the input and the other for output. Return the output from the function.

```
char* uppercase(char input[], char output[]) {
    int i=0;
    for(i = 0; input[i]; i++) {
        output[i] = toupper(input[i]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Use it as:

```
// Define an array for the output of uppercase.
char output[100]; //

case 'C': case 'c':
{
   printf ("The string: %s \n", uppercase(inputt, output));
}
break;
```

Comment: Does that actually cause a seg fault? Doesn't C understand that a string is a single character in length and treat it like a 1 char string? or am i mistaken?

Comment: No, it does not treat the single character as a string of length 1.

Comment: so how I should avoid this mistake?
I use it as char[] in a loop

Comment: @DhmonHossin, please post more of your code. It's hard to suggest something sensible without seeing more code.

Comment: It seems some of the problem fixed but, the out appear like this "���� "

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're segfaulting while looping through the `inputt` array. This could be because the size of the `inputt` array is arbitrary and the length of the `len` array is constant (at 100). So, I assume you are converting a single word or something short, then you try to read outside the `inputt` array and BAM! segfault. (The segfault is most likely in the for loop, when evaluating `inputt[i]` to see if the loop should continue.)

I would recommend reading the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) (yes, it's on C++ site, don't worry) on the `toupper` function, and also passing in the length of the string you wish to convert to the `uppercase` function.

Comment: Here is a C standard site. Just gonna reference it here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_toupper.htm